# Why does django rest framework app works locally, but can only do GET requests when deployed to heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I cannot do methods other than GET when accessing the API on heroku. Else, I get a 500 internal server error.

I suspected that it had to do with permissions:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json',
    # Authentication Scheme
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    # Permission Policies
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
```

However, when I tried commenting out the DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES, I still couldn't log in.

I am using django-rest-auth if that helps (https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Again, it works on my local server (I haven't tried heroku local though). What else am I missing?

Comment: "Else, I get a 500 internal server error… I suspected that it had to do with permissions"—don't _suspect_. Read your logs and find out for sure. Start by running `heroku logs`.

Comment: my logs just seem to let me know information about the client (the time of the request and the browser). Am I missing something?

Comment: "Am I missing something?"—you haven't shown us your logs so how could we know? If you aren't getting any useful errors in your logs, add some logging to the endpoints that are failing.

Comment: I wasn't sure if anything in here is sensitive. But I've combed through multiple times now, and nothing in it is relevant to the error data

Comment: Then, as I said before, add some logging to the problematic endpoints.